# Dojo Tree Grid not being styled correctly

Tags: dojo, xpages

I have created a Dojo Tree Grid using this blog post from Brad Balassatis:  http://xcellerant.net/2013/05/28/categorized-dojo-grid/

The grid is created, but the styling is totally off.

It should look like this:

[image]

But instead it looks like this:

[image]

These are the things I have tried:

- Verified that CSS is loaded using Chrome Dev tools in the Network tab
- Verified that the CSS for the grid is being loaded last
- Commented out bootstrap CSS to verify that dojo and bootstrap were not conflicting
- Moved resource files from CC to Xpage and back (no difference as expected)
- Disabling theme for that control

Here is the resources loaded:

```
    <xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.grid.TreeGrid"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Here is the code that loads the grid in the clientside onClientLoad event

```
var layout = [
  { name: "Arrival Date", field: "state", width: "200px"},
  { name: "PO Number", field: "poNumber", width: "200px"},
  { name: "PO Type", field: "typePO", width: "200px"}
];

var jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ url: "xReadCategorizedView.xsp"});

var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
  store: jsonStore,
  query: {type: 'state'},
  rootId: 'personRoot',
  rootLabel: 'People',
  childrenAttrs: ['children']
});

var grid = new dojox.grid.TreeGrid({
  treeModel: treeModel,
  structure: layout
}, 'treeGrid');

grid.startup();

dojo.connect(window, "onresize", grid, "resize");
```

---

**Complete code as requested.**

**CC containing the grid:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" dojoTheme="true" dojoParseOnLoad="true">

    <xp:this.afterPageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(userStore == "vendor" & vendorBean.vendorNum == null){refreshVendorBean();}}]]></xp:this.afterPageLoad>
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.grid.TreeGrid"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">    </xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"></xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:styleSheet     href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>



    <xe:keepSessionAlive id="keepSessionAlive1" delay="300"></xe:keepSessionAlive>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:panel>
        <xp:div style="text-align:left">
            <xp:label value="By Arrival Date" id="label1"
                style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;color:rgb(0,0,64);font-size:14pt;padding-left:3.0em">
            </xp:label>
        </xp:div>
        <xp:div style="width:100%;height:1000px">
            <div id="treeGrid"></div>
        </xp:div>


    </xp:panel>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var layout = [
  { name: "Arrival Date", field: "state", width: "200px"},
  { name: "PO Number", field: "poNumber", width: "200px"},
  { name: "PO Type", field: "typePO", width: "200px"}
];           
var jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ url: "xReadCategorizedView.xsp"});

var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
  store: jsonStore,
  query: {type: 'state'},
  rootId: 'personRoot',
  rootLabel: 'People',
  childrenAttrs: ['children']
});

var grid = new dojox.grid.TreeGrid({
  treeModel: treeModel,
  structure: layout
}, 'treeGrid');

grid.startup();

dojo.connect(window, "onresize", grid, "resize");]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:view>
```

**XPage containing the CC that contains the grid:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(session.getEffectiveUserName() == "Anonymous"){
    context.redirectToPage("Home.xsp")
}}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xc:layout>
        <xc:Submitted_By_Arrival_CC /></xc:layout></xp:view>
```

**Layout CC that everything is wrapped in.  Uses Bootstrap 2**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter'
        rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!-- Fix for IE8 -->
    <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1"
        rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE(0,8)}">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"<style type='text/css'>body {padding-top: 45px; padding-bottom: 40px; }</style>"}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <xc:header showCategories="true" />
        <div class="row-fluid">

            <div id="mainContent" class="span12">
                <xp:callback />
            </div>
            <div id="rightColumn" class="span0 visible-desktop">
                <xp:callback facetName="rightColumn" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</xp:view>
```

**My theme, originally based on Collaboration Today from openNTF:**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd">

<resources>
    <styleSheet type="text/css" href="bootstrap-2.0.4.combined.min.css"/>
    <styleSheet type="text/css" href="custom.css"/>

    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" clientSide="true" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script src="bootstrap-2.0.4.min.js" clientSide="true" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script src="/custom.js" clientSide="true" type="text/javascript"/>
    <metaData name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,  maximum-scale=1"/>
</resources>

<control override="false">
    <name>ViewRoot</name>
    <property>
        <name>pageTitle</name>
        <value>Harmons Purchase Orders</value>
    </property>
</control>
<control>
    <name>ViewRoot</name>
    <property>
        <name>pageIcon</name>
        <value>/favicon.ico</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

Comment: I try it my self and get the right css. Please post the source code of the whole xpages

Comment: Do you use "Use runtime optimized JavaScript and CSS resources" property?

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth - changing this setting has no difference.

Comment: @adminfd - I have added the complete code including parent pages.  The only thing I didn't include was the xAgent which except for the view location, is unchanged from Brad's blog post.  Thanks for you help

Comment: Are you also loading the general dijit.css?

Comment: @MattR The XPages platform handles loading the dojo for me.  It is loading dojo 1.8.3.  It is tightly integrated into the platform, the TreeGrid isn't part of the core which is why I have to specify the modules and stylesheets.

Comment: @SteveZavocki: try this, load the CSS File, dojoModule, dojoParseOnLoad="true" and dojoTheme="true" in the Xpages, not in the  CC. Hope it helps#

Comment: @SteveZavocki: it could also be that the css that a loaded in the theme (bootstrap.css and custom.css) be in competition with the css of the treeGrid. Try this, don't load the css in the theme or better load the treeGrid.css before bootstrap.css and custom.css over the theme

Comment: @adminfd I tried both of those suggestions already, but I will go ahead and try them again.  About ready to give up here and take a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help @adminfd, like I knew, neither option worked.  Going with a different non-dojo approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the sample code and found that the problem is fixed when adding this attribute to the theme's `<theme>` tag:

```
extends="webstandard"
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem, i have a custom theme and am using the extends default how can i fix this problem  without using the extends="webstandard"?